# Cannot boot, ending in (initramfs), and kernel panic

Tags: boot, grub2

After getting some errors upgrading the Linux kernel packages with `apt` (including insufficient disk space on the boot partition, where the images are stored), I couldn't boot any more.

First, on my setup: I have one hard disk, `/dev/sda` with one boot partition `/dev/sda1` (this is where the kernel images are stored, and was mounted to /boot). The "root" partition is `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--usbkey-root`.

More precisely:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 976771071 976269314 465.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 976771071 976269312 465.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

---

```
$ ls /dev/mapper
control  ubuntu--vg--usbkey-root  ubuntu--vg--usbkey-swap_1
```

---

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV     VG               Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg-usbkey -wi-a----- 457.51g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg-usbkey -wi-a-----  <7.96g
```

---

```
$ lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                      7:0    0   1.7G  1 loop /rofs
loop1                      7:1    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop2                      7:2    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop3                      7:3    0   1.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop4                      7:4    0  12.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop5                      7:5    0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop6                      7:6    0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
sda                        8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0   243M  0 part 
├─sda2                     8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                     8:5    0 465.5G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg--usbkey-root
  │                      253:0    0 457.5G  0 lvm  /mnt
  └─ubuntu--vg--usbkey-swap_1
                         253:1    0     8G  0 lvm  
sdb                        8:16   1   1.9G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sdb1                     8:17   1   1.8G  0 part 
└─sdb2                     8:18   1   2.3M  0 part 
sr0                       11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

My last attempt was to follow the instructions from [this article](https://zeldor.biz/2010/12/install-grub-from-chroot/).

So I did the following:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--usbkey-root /mnt/
$ sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
$ sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
$ sudo chroot /mnt

# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-127-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-127-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-124-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-124-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
done
```

Is this warning an issue? Anyway, I then did the following:

```
# /usr/sbin/grub-install --recheck --no-floppy /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Then I rebooted, and I was lead to a `(initramfs)` prompt. The screen contained the following error message:

```
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1
```

However, I checked `/dev/sda1` with `fsck` from the bootable USB key and it reports no errors... Same for `/dev/sda5/`.

Also, the command

(initramfs) ls /root

reports the contents of `/dev/sda1`. 
However, besides the expected content, there is also a directory `/root/boot/grub`:

```
(initramfs) ls /root/boot/grub
fonts locale grubenv i386-pc
```

Running

```
(initramfs) exit
```

brings me to a screen which ends with

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

All this is quite confusing to me. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, If your boot partition filled 243MB I would suspect you have at least one backup kernel in your boot partition. Have you tried going under grub's advanced boot options and boot off an older kernel version to see if it will boot? (the grub menu comes up on Ubuntu by holding shift during boot)

From what you already attempted, although those command are generally useful for fixing a non-booting system, none (to my understanding) will reduce space used or increase space capacity of your boot partition.

My first guess would be that your boot partition couldn't fit the whole file for the new kernel, but the incomplete kernel was set as the primary boot option in grub.

Comment: The disk space was probably what triggered the problem, but I've removed older kernel images, and now there is enough space. Also, I've tried all 3 available kernel versions, and they all lead to the same error.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't imagine a previously working kernel image to stop working from running out of space. Perhaps there are other forces at work here. Maybe try `sudo update-initramfs -u` then reboot.